# Is there a static URL that can be used to always view the details of the latest version of a package?

Tags: nuget

I've published a package to nuget.org. I recently added icons to the package, so I updated it with a new version number. The version number is part of the URL to the details. I have a link to that page on my project site, but I don't want to have to update that link everytime a new version is released.

Is there a static URL that will always take me to the latest version of a given package?

In case you're wondering, my package is called Args, and the URL to the latest version of the detail page (at the time of writing) is http://nuget.org/Packages/Packages/Details/Args-1-0-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as of now. We just updated nuget.org. More info here:

http://twitter.com/#!/anglicangeek/status/45386847362363392

So your new url would be:

http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Args

Comment: Thanks! This is much nicer, once less thing I need to update when I push out new version.